# Rap/Instrumentals on Pandora or other web apps

Tags: webapp-rec, music, pandora

I like having music available anywhere I go. I also like to freestyle. I'm looking for a web app that has a good selection of rap beats. Really I want something that has a shuffle mechanism, where it will play a random one.

On Pandora, the best I could find were hip hop instrumentals, and the selection was very limited. I need it to be free. I don't mind making an account and having to log in to use it, but not registering is better for me. I'm running out of search queries to find something like this.

Where can I find such a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com/)? [Here](http://soundcloud.com/groups/hip-hop-beats) is a group called "Hip Hop Beats", that contains more than 7500 tracks.

Comment: Thanks!  SoundCloud has some great stuff (from what I've seen so far).

Answer (score 0):

Try `Hip hop insturmentals` on Pandora. Just search `hip hop instrumentals` and go all the way to the bottom and it will be there.